# How to access parent abstract class of model in Django

Tags: python, django, class, inheritance

*(using dajngo 1.9 and python 2.7)*

So I have an abstract class with a few child classes. It looks like this :

```
class Node(models.Model):

    [...]
    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Individual(Node):
    [...]


class Company(Node):
    [...]


class Media(Node):
    [...]


class Share(models.Model):
    share = models.FloatField(null=True)

    child_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='child')
    child_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    child = GenericForeignKey('child_content_type', 'child_object_id')

    parent_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='parent')
    parent_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    parent = GenericForeignKey('parent_content_type', 'parent_object_id')
```

The thing is that, virtually, the Share's child and parent can take any model in. So I want to implement an extended save() method (for Share) that will check that both the child and the parent inherit from Node.

I'm looking for something that could look like this :

```
assert child.inherited_class.name == 'node'
assert parent.inherited_class.name == 'node'
```

(or with `child_content_type` of ocurse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
assert isinstance(child, Node)
assert isinstance(parent, Node)
```